# Ordering by multiple columns in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am building a small app that shows the cheapest price for a product by area. I need the result from my database to show only one result per area, and that result must have the lowest price of all rows for that area.

I've come up with this so far, which is nearly there but mixes up the result rows.

```
SELECT `products`.`id`, `products`.`area_id`, `products`.`date`, 
`products`.`duration`, MIN(`products`.`price`) AS `price`, `products`.`rating`,
`products`.`buy_url` FROM `products` WHERE `price` >= '0' GROUP BY `products`.`area_id` ORDER BY 
`price` ASC
```

Although this successfully returns only one result per area, using `MIN()` here seems to get the lowest price for that area, but the other columns will be from a different row (i.e. the row that would have been selected in its entirety had I not used `MIN()` above).

So, I obviously have this wrong. I'd be really grateful for some advice on how I can select the lowest 'price', along with the rest of that row, from each distinct `area`.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: where is `FROM` clause??

Comment: Ah - my mistake in simplifying my SQL for the question. It is there in the real thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t1.* from products as t1
inner join (
select area_id,min(price) as price
from products where price > 0
group by area_id) as t2
on t1.area_id = t2.area_id and t1.price = t2.price


alter table products add index i (area_id,price);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nick - this works. It is quite slow on my database (10-12 seconds on my 85k rows now, will be ~750k rows when live), though. Is there any faster alternative?

Comment: @Mateo. Add an index to your table on (area_id,price)

Comment: Can you tell us about performance after you've added the index?

Comment: @nick Select without index: 4.9s. After index: 0.0087s. Huge difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `products`.`id`, `products`.`area_id`, `products`.`date`, `products`.`duration`, MIN(`products`.`price`) AS `price`, `products`.`rating`, `products`.`buy_url` WHERE `price` >= '0' GROUP BY `products`.`id`, `products`.`area_id`, `products`.`date`, `products`.`duration`,  `products`.`rating`, `products`.`buy_url` ORDER BY `price` ASC
```

You'll have to group by all the columns you are selecting.

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks for your suggestion. This didn't work - it returned rows with duplicate area_ids.

Comment: If you want just the areaid and the minimum price, that can be done by selecting the area and min(price) alone. But if an area has different product dates, durations, ratings, etc. You'll have to decide which of those you want. For example you can SELECT areaid, min(price), max(ratings), sum(durations)....

Answer (score 0):

what about this

```
SELECT MIN(p1.price) AS minPrice, 
p1.id, p1.area_id, p1.date, p1.duration,p1.rating,p1buy_url 
FROM products p1
LEFT JOIN products p2
ON (p1.area_id=p2.area.id AND p1.id<p2.id)
WHERE p2.id is NULL
GROUP BY area_id 
ORDER BY p1.id ASC
```

**note:** you can not `order by` on a field( here u mention `minPrice`) which is not exist in table

> **LEFT JOIN** is faster than **INNER JOIN** as u can check by using `EXPLAIN` keyword before `SELECT`

[Reference Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Comment: Hi, this created some kind of (endless?) loop - the query never finished. Edit: actually this comment refers to your pre-edit solution - am trying your updated solution now.

Comment: i have tries on my mysql, it works fine.  remove `ORDER BY` CLAUSE completely